# Lévy process, indicator function, sojourn time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, characteristic-functions, levy-processes, local-time

Given a one dimensional Lévy process $X_t$ with characteristic exponent $\psi(\xi)$, so that
\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}[e^{i \xi X_t}]= e^{t \psi(\xi)}
\end{align}
for example we can find $\psi(\xi)$ from Lévy–Khintchine representation.

What can I say on the function $1_{X_t \in A}$? Its Laplace transform? Where $1_{X_t \in A}$ is the indicator function, then it is $1$ if $X_t \in A$, $0$ otherwise. $A$ can be an interval or a point of $\mathbb{R}$. From a probabilistic point of view, the knowledge of $\psi(\xi)$ allows us to understand which is the sojourn time (or local time) of the process $X_t$ in $A$ ?

Thank you very much!